# Swagger-codegen enforcement of "required" fields in Definitions

Tags: swagger, maven-plugin, swagger-codegen

I have these fields marked as required in my yaml file (swagger spec)

```
  MyType:
    type: object
    required:
      - name
      - amount
```

I am using swagger codegen maven plugin with these configurations:

```
<artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2.3</version>

<language>spring</language>
<library>spring-mvc</library>
```

I would like to have required fields in spec to be made required in the generated classes as well. But that is not happening currently.

Are there configuration options to do that? I have `<useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>` but this does not seem to work for me.

I saw a similar request [enforcement of "required" fields in Definitions](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6883) on Swagger-codegen GitHub page where suggestion was to use `useBeanValidation` and I do have it but it still does not work.

Created this request on Swagger-codegen GitHub page: [Swagger-codegen enforcement of “required” fields in generated model classes](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7962)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. It was actually my mistake; I was expecting the *field* in the generated class to be marked required. It is rather the *getter* method which is annotated with `@NonNull` and `required = true` which solves the purpose. And now with the validation in place, I am able to see the validation is triggered and showing the message `Amount should be present` when amount is not passed in the request payload.

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "Amount should be present")
@NotNull
public Amount getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how exactly you configured your validation? I can't make it work when the annotation is not on the field itself. When do you check whether it is @Valid?